# NUnit tests fail due to Enterprise Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit, enterprise-library

I've seen several questions here dealing with similar problems but none of them have helped me.

I am using NUnit with VS 2010 in an MVC 3 project. 
I have a Tests project and am writing my first tests Evar! :-)

Aren't you proud I finally am getting to it?!

Here is the error I am getting

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException : Activation
>   error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key
>   "MyConnection"   ---->
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException : Resolution of
>   the dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name =
>   "MyConnection". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed.
>   You must configure the container to supply this value.

I have configured the `web.config` with all this and the data returns perfectly when not running in a test so I know it's not the config that is dying per ce, it's just dying when used with NUnit.

Here is my connection info:

```
<section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
...
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="MyConnection" />
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have installed the DaaB using NuGet and also doing a clean manual reference. Either way, the data loads fine in normal usage but in testing it dies at this line:

```
var database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyConnection");
```

In this method

```
public IEnumerable<SchoolSearchResultsDTO> Find(SchoolSearchInputDTO dto) {
    List<SchoolSearchResultsDTO> fullList;
    var database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyConnection");
    using (var command = database.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.usp_School_SearchBySchoolName")) {
        database.AddInParameter(command, "@I_strSchoolName", DbType.String, dto.SearchTerm);
        database.AddInParameter(command, "@I_intNumberOfRecords", DbType.Int32, dto.MaxSearchResults);
        using (var reader = database.ExecuteReader(command)) {
            fullList = new List<SchoolSearchResultsDTO>();
            while (reader.Read()) {
                var fullRecord = new SchoolSearchResultsDTO();
                fullRecord.SchoolID = reader.GetInteger("SchoolId");
                fullRecord.SchoolName = reader.GetString("SchoolName");
                fullRecord.IsDetailedDisplayMode = reader.GetBoolean("IsDetailedDisplayMode");
                fullList.Add(fullRecord);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    return fullList;
}
```

All the other posts talk about misconfiguration etc.. I'm pretty sure I'm configured correctly otherwise I wouldn't get data under normal usage. So it has to do with NUnit and DaaB together.

Any bright ideas? :-)
Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with @Jesse regarding mocking dependencies. If you're not isolating the sut then its not a unit test. (recommended reading [Art of UnitTesting](http://artofunittesting.com/))

So moving on from that, you could say you are writing integrations tests.

Without looking at your exact setup, it's hard to tell what the issue is.  One thing you mentioned was you have "configured your `web.config`".

But have you setup a config file in your test project? The config will be loaded from your unit test project, not the MVC project.

Comment: Great information! Thanks! I never really thought of my test project needing any special config on it's own. I guess I'm still floundering here in my attempts.

Comment: Adding an app.config to the Test project fixed it :-) Thanks for the info. By the way I have the book, haven't started it yet but just started the TDD Master Course (by the book's author, Roy Osherove) on TekPub yesterday and was following along till I got hung up on this. Thanks for the leg up! :-)

Comment: Good stuff mate, TDD will be the single biggest change in the way you code. After the initial few hurdles, I think you'll find it will make you far more productive.

Comment: Uncle bob has a good episode on TDD here, demonstrating the Bowling Application. It's a little contrived, but Uncle Bob is a legend.  http://www.cleancoders.com/codecast/clean-code-episode-6-part-2/show

Comment: Yeah I read his Clean Code book twice and Clean Coder as well. I started watching the episodes a few weeks ago with the first one but haven't gotten back to them. Anything contrived, which I agree, it truly is, always grates on me. I tend to need to work with a real situation that I'm dealing with otherwise I don't feel like I can apply the learning.

Comment: I also read Mark Seeman's book on DI in .net but found it very unhelpful. I get DI, I understand it very well, what he spends almost no time showing is a true Composition Root and how to use it. I can ctor inject all day long but if I don't know how to build the piece that does all that resolution then it's no help. I typically build large multi tier apps, so DI with TDD in use would really help. but all I hear from people is in a large solution DI becomes hard to do, well THAT'S when it's most important!!!! sorry, ranting.

Comment: By the way, I met Uncle Bob in April, I won an 8th light t-shirt from him for knowing who first used the sun in his calculations in determining the earth was spherical and the order of the current visible planets in that night's sky :-) He's an awesomely smart man, maybe too smart :-)

Comment: Hey that's cool. re: composition root: it all depends on the application you are creating, Seeman has an entire chapter dedicated to the Composition Root, covering the main .net applications. e.g. The composition root of an MVC app is the ControllerFactory. Read it again, Chapter 7 Object Composition.

Comment: Yeah I read that, I'l have to read again. I just need to *see* one and see how the solution is laid out an how it's all referenced. SO I have a sample app using Castle Windsor with a root and am trying to apply the same thing to my app :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is good practice to avoid hitting a database directly within a unit test. I would recommend setting aside sometime to read about mocking in regards to creating valuable and reliable unit tests. With mocking, you can inject into the related controller a mocked service layer, which would be setup to return your expected database data.

Within your test you would create a mock of that service layer. For an example utilizing [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) (my mocking framework preference):

```
// create your expected data
var YourExpectedData = new IList<SchoolSearchResultsDTO>();

// .... add your expected information

//create & setup mock
var _service = new Mock<IYourService>();
_service.Setup(service => service.Find(It.IsAny<SchoolSearchInputDTO>())).Returns(YourExpectedData);

// create your controller
var controller = new YourCountroller(_service.object())
```

From this point on your unit test is quite straight forward. Any time the method find is called within the various code your testing the mock kicks in and returns your expected data.

Comment: See, this is why I love SO! Ok so this I didn't know. I just assumed that I was testing behavior and the behavior I was expecting is to return data and validate that I got what I asked for. So I'm not sure how to handle that. Some background, the app is nothing more than a UI that allows a user to search for a school and see data about that school. There's no business logic, no data updating, and in my opinion, nothing more to test than "Did the user search input give back what was expected?" I don't see how mocking that will give me real useful info.

Comment: But as jflood says, these types of tests are more integration tests than unit tests. Is that right? Am I wasting time even trying to do testing with this kind of app?

Comment: That is exactly the point of Mocking. Mocking removes the dependency of the database. A test database needs to be setup and maintained to ensure that the input returned to the test is valid. With a mock your "expected data" is always what you set it to be. That way you can ensure that the functionality your testing is not reliant on your database. That said, if you want to explore an integration type test approach that makes use of your database I would recommend: http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I went over all this with my mgr and he agrees and assumed I just knew this. Well I didn't. Thanks! I think I see the light! I now have mocks that implement my repository interfaces and supply test data that won't change so regression testing can be more accurately predicted.